# How to restore TensorFlow 's checkpoint in changed parameters and model?

Tags: tensorflow, restore, checkpoint

I restore a saved parameters of a model in tensorflow. I want test difference configure for my model with different layer and different parameters size.

for example if one of my parameters that I saved be like this:
`W_conv1 = weight_variable([7 , 7, 1, 64])`

if I restore this, it works; but I want change my parameter like this :
 `W_conv1 = weight_variable([5 , 5, 1, 64])`
or
`W_conv1 = weight_variable([5 , 5, 1, 50])`
or
`W_conv1 = weight_variable([9 , 9, 1, 80])`
or ... .

Now I want used my saved checkpoint for restore in new config. If the size of each dimension of parameters changed it randomly initialized from my saved parameter and remind places initialize randomly.

Is it possible in tensorflow for doing this?

Comment: Can use the `reshape = True` in `tf.train.saver`?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow provides operators to obtain a slice of an existing variable ([`tf.slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice)), and also operators to assign a value (possibly a slice) to an existing variable ([`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#assign)). So, what you want can be achieved with the following steps :

- Restore your old variable from the checkpoint
- Create your new variable of different shape, initialized randomly
- Assign the relevant slice of your old variable to the new variable

For instance, if your old variable has the shape `[7, 7, 1, 64]` and your new variable has the shape `[5, 5, 1, 64]`, here is a recipe for slicing the old variable and assigning to the new variable :

```
# old_variable has the shape [7, 7, 1, 64]
new_variable = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(5, 5, 1, 64))
assign_new_var = tf.assign(new_variable, old_variable([:5, :5, :, :]))
```

Comment: When I used this code `tf.assign(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7200, 1000], stddev = std)), W_fc1)` it makes error : `ValueError: Shapes (7200, 1000) and (7200, 150) are not compatible`  where  `W_fc1 = weight_variable([7200, 150])`

Comment: If you are trying to assign a `7200 x 150` tensor to a `7200 x 1000` variable, *and* you want the resulting variable to be `7200 x 100`, then you will need to use [`tf.pad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) to convert it to the correct size.